# Erroneously using STDIN when pasting a script into the Terminal.app

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, irb, highline

I have the following script-snipped, which I use regularly to semi-automate one of my workflows. 
I open a bash terminal and start irb and then paste the script:

```
require 'highline/import'

# ...
user = ask("User:")
repo = ask("Repository:")
# ...
# Do advanced fancy stuff
```

Now I want to be able to paste this into the terminal, but the first prompt for the user is overwritten by the following line: `repo = ask("Repository:")`.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour.

I know that I could write a script. But

1. I find it convenient to be able to just paste this into the terminal
2. I wonder how the STDIN can be somehow outfoxed in this case

Comment: Where do you paste it in from? ;) Wouldn't it be just as convenient to `load` those lines?

Comment: @TomFenech I copy this from my notes. I use such script snippets quite often and there is always a terminal open when I am working on a given project. So loading it from some path is not what I want...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent this behaviour.

You can prevent the echoing of pasted text with the command

```
stty -echo
```

- whether you like that is another question, since this inevitably also prevents the echoing of typed-in commands, but you can see again after entering

```
stty echo
```